# Consequences to QGIS of changing PostGIS table to 3D?

Tags: qgis, postgis

In QGIS add vector layer creates a layer with 3D geometry.  All my postGIS tables have been created with 2D so I can not save them to PostGIS.

Are there any problems with converting my existing 2D tables to 3D to get around this?

I am aware that QGIS 3 will allow one to drop the z dimension but this question is explicitly about converting tables to 3D.

Comment: Your question is about creating new layers in postgis but using existing ones from postgis. There seems to be a mismatch here. Do you mean using and editing existing postgis layer from QGIS?

Comment: Furthermore I don't see problems with converting existing 2D tables to 3D, but I'm a little surprised this is needed with QGIS.

Comment: I am importing data from a GPS into QGIS and then adding it a master layer that is backed by PostGIS.  When I try and save the updated master I get errors about the 3D data.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a master layer that is backed by PostGIS'. Is it a postgis layer or is it something else? Do you create that master layer yourself or is it already there? Please describe step-by-step what you are doing.

Comment: it is a vector layer which is defined by an sql query on a PostGIS db.  It contains all my waypoints -- I have another that contains all lines.  The problem comes when I try to save the updated vector layer to PostGIS.   QGIS 3 will deal with this but in the mean time it is painful.

Comment: Then my answer is: 'No, there is no problem with converting your existing 2D tables to 3D'.

Comment: Thanks! If you formally answer the question I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with converting your existing 2D tables to 3D, apart from your data becoming slightly larger with an extra z-coordinate (with value 0) attached to it.